# How i can find picture xml jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

XML code

```
<sterowniki>
    <items id="1" name="name" >
        <opis>Lorem lipsum</opis>
        <zdjecie picture="img/car.png"> </zdjecie>
    </items>
</sterowniki>
```

jQuery question

```js
function parseXml(xml) {      
    var id_elem = $.urlParam('id');
    $(xml).find("sterowniki").each(function() { 
        $(xml).find('items[id="' + id_elem + '"]').each(function() {   
            $("#nazwa").append('<h3 align="center"class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-8"><b>' + $(this).attr('name') + '</b></h3>');
            $("#opis").append($(this).find('opis').text());
            $("#foto").append('<img src="' + $(this).attr('picture') + '" class="img-thumbnail col-xs-5 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4" />'); 
        });
    });    
}
```

In this way, I can not display the image on the page. Does my query there any error?
Thank you

Comment: What is `this`? You need to show full jQuery code.

Comment: What is `this` a reference to? Please post your full jQuery code.

Comment: what is shown in the html? And what is "foto" is that a div?

Comment: You have a typo, it should be `src` (`<img src="'+$(this).attr('picture')+'" .../>`), not `scr`.

Comment: XML in the database I want to put the path to the images with the extension .png, and display them on the page using jQuery question what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am add full jQuery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `find()` to get the `zdjecie` element of your XML, then `attr` to get the `picture` property. Try this:

```
$("#foto").append('<img src="' + $(this).find('zdjecie').attr('picture') + '" class="img-thumbnail col-xs-5 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4" />');
```